# What happens to a virtual function when assigning a subclass to its superclass?

Tags: c++

Say I have class `B` that derives from class `A`. If `B` overrides a virtual method `f` of class `A`, what exactly happens with this virtual method when I assign an instance of class `B` into an instance of class `A`?

Most basic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
  public:
    virtual void f()
    {
      printf("I am A\n");
    }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    virtual void f()
    {
      printf("I am B\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
  // Instance of B:
  B b;
  b.f();

  // Reference to A:
  A& a_ref = b;
  a_ref.f();

  // Assignment:
  A a = b;
  a.f();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[windel@hoefnix]$ g++ wtf.cpp
[windel@hoefnix]$ ./a.out 
I am B
I am B
I am A
```

When using a reference, all is going as expected, but with a cast, I was put on the wrong foot here.

Comment: Your final example is not _casting_  - doing `A a = b;` slices the `B` to an `A`, so both the static and dynamic type of `a` is an A.

Comment: Just a quick helpful note: you only get polymorphism in C++ when you use a *reference* or a *pointer* to an object.

Comment: It's also not assignment happening at that point, even though you wrote =